# Prevent new tab from closing previous tab in Firefox

Tags: firefox, tabs

I'm on Firefox 59.0.1.

Some adult image sites have a feature where clicking a link would open a new tab while closing the parent tab, *i.e.* the tab on which I clicked the link.

I have the "[Don't touch my tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dont-touch-my-tabs/)" extension installed, which does not stop this behaviour.

I've tried blocking scripts on the image sites, which simply breaks the entire site.

Is there an in-browser way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Replacing the current tab is the default behavior.  I believe there is a setting to make "open in new tab" the default.  You can also right-click on the link and select the "open in new tab" option.

Comment: Just ctrl click new link... just do it

Comment: Essentially, the advertising tab takes over the parent tab.  You already received some great advice from @fixer1234:  if you right-click the hyperlink and select **Open Link in New Tab**, it will open your desired tab *and* the advertising tab separately while leaving your original tab intact.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem until I found that the uBlock Origin add-on has an option 'Click to block all popups on this site'.

Funny thing is that I was looking for the same fix as you are a while ago but it was in uBlock Origin the whole time which I've been using for years!! Took me ages to find the answer though.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  It isn't clear what blocking popups has to do with the question.

Comment: The relevance is that some sites, out of a combination of malice and ignorance / stupidity, have links (`<a …>`) with an `onclick` attribute that calls JavaScript code that *explicitly* opens a new URL in a new tab (bypassing the normal `href=` mechanism) and then maybe does something else in the original tab. That’s what the question is about, and that’s why the Q mentions “blocking scripts”. A page that is opened in a new tab by a call to JavaScript’s `open()` function probably looks enough like a pop-up to be blocked by this add-on. But I’m not clear how this *answers* the question, either.